# can i use my flutter codes that i wrote in android studio or visual studio for ios?and how?

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, flutter

I just started learning flutter and I have a question.

**1**-is it possible to compile the code that in the android studio or visual studio straight to ios?

**2**-if I cannot compile it straight to ios, can I use those codes and compile them with Xcode in a macos without any change in them(flutter codes that i wrote in the android studio or visual studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need Xcode installed though.

A Flutter project built in Android Studio compiles directly for iOS.

You can build directly for iOS from Android Studio, but Xcode needs to be installed.

You can also

build from a terminal using `flutter build ios --release`

debug from withing Android Studio a Flutter project running on an iOS simulator or device.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

You just have to open the application using Xcode and run it on you iOS device or emulator.  Please note that iOS apps can only be built and tested (on both emulators and real devices) on macOS!

Run flutter doctor to detect any setup problems that might need to be fixed.

Also use that native IDEs (Android Studio for Android, XCode for iOS) to build + run your app.